# On Twitter, how can I find people most followed by the people that I follow?

Tags: twitter, followers

Twitter recommends who you might want to follow and indicates a couple of people-that-I-follow that follow them. But no mention of how many others.

If you click on the recommendation you can get their profile summary that indicates they are followed by A, B, C, and 100+ others of the people-that-I-follow.

If you ask for the full list (View All) of people recommended to follow then you get a list which indicates they are followed by A, B, C. But no mention of how many others.

It's the how-many-others statistic that interests me. I'm more likely to follow someone if more of the people-that-I-follow also follow them.

But there's no way I can see to list recommended people that I might want to follow in such a way that I can see which ones have more of the people-that-I-follow who also follow them.

Am I missing something?